# Where can i check the logs of GA4 Automatically collected events? (notification_open event)

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-analytics-4

What I want to know is, the number of 'notification_open' event divided by the message ID.
In this page, i can see the event has 'message_id' parameter.

[https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9234069?hl=en](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIeSb.png)

But where can i check the logs with these parameters?

In GA and Firebase Console, i can see the total number of events.

But Is there any way to check the events with the parameters?
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Those data are available in [BigQuery export](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/bigquery-export). You just have to link your Firebase app to BigQuery. From there, you can access your [raw analytics data](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846)  along with the parameters you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Now i'm getting datas in 'events_intraday_YYYYMMDD' table in BigQuery! but why do i can't find column named 'message_id'?  @Yuji Bry